# Expected number and probability of a series of 1s in a bit string.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bit-strings

Suppose the sequence `1001111011011` has a total of $4$ "blocks" of one, because number of contiguous sequences made of ones (`1`, `1111`,`11` and `11`) count to 4. Given a random bit array of length $N$, what's the expected value of the "number of 1 blocks"? Related to that, what is the probability there are $M$ blocks in a bit a array of length $N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $z$  for zeros  and $w$  for ones and  $u$ for  runs we  get the
generating function

$$(1+z+z^2+\cdots)
\\ \times \sum_{q\ge 0} u^{q} (w+w^2+\cdots)^q (z+z^2+\cdots)^q
\\ \times (1+uw+uw^2+\cdots)$$

which is

$$\frac{1}{1-z}
\\ \times \sum_{q\ge 0} u^{q} \frac{w^q}{(1-w)^q} \frac{z^q}{(1-z)^q}
\\ \times \left(1+u\frac{w}{1-w}\right)$$

or

$$\frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1-uwz/(1-z)/(1-w)}
\frac{1-w+uw}{1-w}
\\ = \frac{1-w+uw}{(1-z)(1-w)-uwz}.$$

As a sanity check we put $u=1$ and $w=z$ to obtain

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2 - z^2} = \frac{1}{1-2z}$$

and we see that we have accounted for all strings of length $N.$ We no
longer need the distinction between zeros and ones here so we obtain

$$\frac{1-z+uz}{(1-z)^2-uz^2}
= \frac{1-z+uz}{(1-z)^2}\frac{1}{1-uz^2/(1-z)^2}
\\ = \left(\frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{uz}{(1-z)^2}\right)
\frac{1}{1-uz^2/(1-z)^2}.$$

Extract the coefficient on $[u^M]$ to get

$$\frac{z^{2M}}{(1-z)^{2M+1}}
+ \frac{z^{2M-1}}{(1-z)^{2M}}
\\ =  \left(\frac{z}{1-z} + 1\right) \frac{z^{2M-1}}{(1-z)^{2M}}
= \frac{z^{2M-1}}{(1-z)^{2M+1}}.$$

Continue with the coefficient on $[z^N]$ to obtain

$$[z^N] \frac{z^{2M-1}}{(1-z)^{2M+1}}
= [z^{N+1-2M}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{2M+1}}
\\ = {N+1-2M+2M\choose 2M} = {N+1\choose 2M}$$

for a probability of

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2^N} {N+1\choose 2M}.}$$

We get for the expectation

$$\sum_{M=0, \; 2M\le N+1} M {N+1\choose 2M}
= \sum_{M=1, \; 2M\le N+1} M {N+1\choose 2M}
\\ = \frac{N+1}{2} \sum_{M=1, \; 2M\le N+1} {N\choose 2M-1}
= \frac{N+1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^N {N\choose q} \frac{1-(-1)^q}{2}
\\ = \frac{N+1}{4} 2^N.$$

Dividing by $2^N$ then yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{N+1}{4}.}$$

This may also be obtained by linearity of expectation. We place a zero
value at the  front of the string  and may then count runs  of ones by
the number  of times  a zero  was followed  by a  one in  the modified
string, which  gives $1/2  + (N-1)/4,$ the  same answer  ($N-1$ places
where we transition from one bit to the next).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: there are $N-1$ places between the bits, each of which either divides a block of `1`s from a block of `0`s or is inside a block. For each possible odd number of dividers between blocks, there is one possible value for the number of blocks of `1`s. For each even number of dividers, there are two (equally likely) possible numbers of `1`-blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Concern an infinite string.

Let $X$ denote the location of the first character in this string that takes value $0$.

For $N\in\mathbb N$ let $S_N$ denote the substring that starts at the first character and has length $N$.

Let $B_N$ denote the number of "one-blocks" of substring $S_N$.

As an example: if we are dealing with $N=12$ and string $101110110111110111110\cdots$ then $X=2$, $S_{12}=101110110111$ and $B_{12}=4$.

Further denote $\mu_N=\mathbb EB_N$ and observe that:

- $\mathbb E(B_N\mid X=1)=\mu_{N-1}$ and
- $\mathbb E(B_N\mid X=k)=1+\mu_{N-k}$ for $k\in\{2,\dots,N-1\}$ and
- $\mathbb E(B_N\mid X=k)=1$ for $k\geq N$

Then working out: $\mathbb EB_N=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb E[B_N\mid X=k]P(X=k)$ we find:$$\mu_N=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\mu_{N-k}2^{-k}+\frac12$$

Based on that we find:

$$\begin{aligned}\mu_{N+1} & =\frac{1}{2}\left[\mu_{N}+2^{-N}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\mu_{k}2^{k}\right]+\frac{1}{2}\\
 & =\frac{1}{2}\left[\mu_{N}+\mu_{N}-\frac{1}{2}\right]+\frac{1}{2}\\
 & =\mu_{N}+\frac{1}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$

This recursion equality leads easily to:$$\mu_N=\frac14N+\frac14$$